# How to detect to which pin connected the sensor?

Tags: android, linux, gpio

I have PIR sensor and MBOX306GS control board with Android. This board has I/O Control Interface with 4 GPIO. I found 91 available pins using command `cat /sys/kernel/debug/gpio`. Then I activated them and tried to read values but with no luck. I've tested this sensor on Orange PI and it worked good. But for this board I can't find the right pin to connect.
Does anyone know how to detect to which pin my sensor connected in Linux, so I could read value changes using command `cat /sys/class/gpio/gpio(here is gpio number)/value`
Here is image of this board (back) and GPIO section
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally find pins that I can detect. There are LVDS pins (70-89) that I can use.

Answer (score 1):

PIR sensor module only have 3 pin: 
 1. GND 
 2. SIGNAL (digital not analog) 
 3. VCC (5 volt DC input)

GND , VCC -> easy to connect PIR GND and VCC pin to android board PIN

Signal Pin -> you can connect it to IO-1 or IO-2 or IO-3 or IO-4 pin on android board after in code you need read signal from seleted pin.

Comment: Thank you for respond. But how can I detect which number should I export using echo %d > /sys/class/gpio/export that is associated with this pin?

Comment: you can try this article to know how to check IO pin correctly Link: https://developer.ridgerun.com/wiki/index.php/How_to_use_GPIO_signals